# How do I convert close Longitude/Latitude points to drawable x/y coordinates in Java?

Tags: java, dictionary, jpanel, coordinates

I'm having trouble converting latitude and longitude coordinates to X/Y coordinates that are suitable for drawing to a JPanel. I can convert them to proper x/y values, however these values are all far too similar and don't differ by enough to actually draw the map I'm trying to draw. I'm using a JPanel with Line2D's, however I've seen examples that use a Polygon but when I did this the map didn't look correct at all.

The lat/long points that I convert are all very close (all lie within a college campus), so my x/y values are also very close. I need a way to conver them so that they are represented in a 600x600 pixel JPanel. Here's an example of some points I convert to XY and their values:

```
GL  43.130480   -77.631559
i2  43.130425   -77.631532
i3  43.130335   -77.631760

--Convert to X/Y--

0 GILBERT-LONG [lat=579.9952509893145, long=502.4890740637273]
44 i2 [lat=579.9950131035996, long=502.4888664711529]
45 i3 [lat=579.997021932372, long=502.48852677421297]
```

Here's my code for conversion, taken from another thread on here, where MAP_HEIGHT and MAP_WIDTH are both 600:

```
public static void toXY()
{
    for(Vertex x : vertices)
    {

        double xVal = (x.coordinate.latitude*MAP_HEIGHT/180) + (MAP_HEIGHT/2);

        double latRad = x.coordinate.longitude*(Math.PI/180);

        double mercatorN = Math.log(Math.tan((Math.PI/4)+(latRad/2)));

        double yVal = (MAP_HEIGHT/2)-(MAP_WIDTH*mercatorN/(Math.PI*2));


        //double yVal = (x.coordinate.longitude * MAP_WIDTH/360.0) + (MAP_WIDTH/2);

        x.coordinate.longitude = xVal;
        x.coordinate.latitude = yVal;
    }
```

I also multiply the x and y's by a scaleFactor that is calculated by finding the min/max's of the X and Y values and finding the ratio of the width/heigh to the different of the max and mins like this:

```
double scaleX = (MAP_WIDTH-20) / (maxX - minX);
double scaleY = (MAP_HEIGHT-20) / (maxY-minY);
```

Comment: Can you upload a picture of what you're seeing? It would be helpful in diagnosing the issue. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the final step, in order to transform the `xVal` value which is between `xMin` and `xMax` into a value between `0` and `MAP_WIDTH-20`, you need something like this:

```
double newX = (xVal - minX) * (MAP_WIDTH-20) / (maxX - minX);
double newY = (yVal - minY) * (MAP_HEIGHT-20) / (maxY - minY);
```

or (using `scaleX` and `scaleY` that you defined):

```
double newX = (xVal - minX) * scaleX;
double newY = (yVal - minY) * scaleY;
```